# How can I print the dates of this nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

How can I print/access just the dates of "Time Series (Daily)"?

I tried the following, but I get a key error:

```
for date in range(0,2):
    print(date)
    print(tickerData['Time Series (Daily)'][date])
```

Here is the nested dictionary:

```
   {
        "Meta Data": {
            "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
            "2. Symbol": "NASDAQ Index",
            "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-04-13",
            "4. Output Size": "Compact",
            "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
        },
        "Time Series (Daily)": {
            "2018-04-13": {
                "1. open": "7179.6201",
                "2. high": "7183.6201",
                "3. low": "7078.1401",
                "4. close": "7106.6499",
                "5. volume": "1743640000"
            },
            "2018-04-12": {
                "1. open": "7112.0200",
                "2. high": "7166.0000",
                "3. low": "7105.0898",
                "4. close": "7140.2500",
                "5. volume": "2021110000"
            }}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tickerData ={
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "NASDAQ Index",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-04-13",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2018-04-13": {
            "1. open": "7179.6201",
            "2. high": "7183.6201",
            "3. low": "7078.1401",
            "4. close": "7106.6499",
            "5. volume": "1743640000"
        },
        "2018-04-12": {
            "1. open": "7112.0200",
            "2. high": "7166.0000",
            "3. low": "7105.0898",
            "4. close": "7140.2500",
            "5. volume": "2021110000"
        }
    }
}

for date in tickerData['Time Series (Daily)'].keys():
    print(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below to get all dates in your dictionary:

```
    dates = tickerdata["Time Series (Daily)"]
    for item in dates:
        print (item)
```

Output:

```
2018-04-13
2018-04-12
```

For Comment below:

Not sure if this is what you want but you can do something like below:

```
class AttributeDict(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
tickerdata = {
        "Meta Data": {
            "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
            "2. Symbol": "NASDAQ Index",
            "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-04-13",
            "4. Output Size": "Compact",
            "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
        },
        "TimeSeriesDaily": {
            "2018-04-13": {
                "1. open": "7179.6201",
                "2. high": "7183.6201",
                "3. low": "7078.1401",
                "4. close": "7106.6499",
                "5. volume": "1743640000"
            },
            "2018-04-12": {
                "1. open": "7112.0200",
                "2. high": "7166.0000",
                "3. low": "7105.0898",
                "4. close": "7140.2500",
                "5. volume": "2021110000"
            }}}


tmp = AttributeDict(tickerdata)
for date in tmp.'TimeSeriesDaily':
    print(date)
```

but if you notice for this your 'Time Series (Daily)' label need to be simplified, which I don't think you may have control or want to do.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty slick!  By chance, do you know if it's possible to directly access the dates without having to pull out the "Time Series (Daily)" object?

Comment: I dont think that is possible straight away but something can be done still not very sure that is how u want it.